# Redirect IP to domain using SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, .htaccess, ip, redirect

I am trying to redirect my IP address to my domain which uses SSL. In my htaccess

I am using following lines:

```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.111\.11\.111$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Redirect works, but before it is redirected I get SSL certificate error, once I click on proceed (unsafe) it goes to the domain. How do I redirect to domain without going to to the SSL certificate page first?

Comment: If someone enters `https://111.111.11.111/` there is no way to redirect them until after they have securely connected.

Comment: Even when I enter http://111.111.11.111/ it redirects to  https://111.111.11.111/  before it goes to my domain

Comment: It might be helpful to state your reasoning for this redirect. There might be a better solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to be possible, you would need a valid SSL certificate for `111.111.11.111`, which is unlikely, see also [Is it possible to have SSL certificate for IP address, not domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name).

What you probably *want* to do is:

1. Create a `VirtualHost` entry matching `111.111.11.111` as `ServerName`, but not using `https`, but `http` instead.
2. Redirect that to your domain.

You might also consider using `mod_alias` instead of `mod_rewrite`, which is considered the cleaner options in this case, see [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html).